# Why is my Socket Client not allowing the outgoing connection in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, sockets, networking, udp

I have created a very simple UDP Socket client and server in python3.
I'm trying to send the simple message 'hello' to the server and I am getting the error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I'm not sure that it's actually the target machine's fault as the target machine is an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance with 'All Traffic Allowed' configured with the security group.

I'm convinced it has to be some sort of outbound policy on my desktop computer...

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

***client.py***

```
import socket

client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect(('servers public ipv4 ip', 8089))
client_sock.send('hello'.encode())
```

***server.py***

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 8089))
s.listen(5) #5 connections

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    buffer = conn.recv(64)
    if len(buffer) > 0:
        print(buffer.decode())
        break
```

Comment: As an aside, `client_sock.send('hello'.encode())` encodes to to the local client's default encoding. You should define what the encoding for this channel is and use that explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, despite your repeated claims (in body and tags) that you are using UDP you are actually using TCP as can be seen from your use of `SOCK_STREAM` and `accept`.

```
 s.bind(('localhost', 8089))
```

You explicitly bind the server to `localhost`. But [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is only the loopback interface of the computer (`127.0.0.1`) which is not reachable from outside. If you want to accept connections from other systems you need to either bind to the IP address of the specific network interface or broadly to `0.0.0.0` - or simply use `s.bind('',8089)`.

Comment: Thank you Steffan, you've helped me a ton :)